# DGS-1005A switch question - which site to go?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've got a question on getting 1 Gbit/s on my D-Link DGS-1005A. I managed to test getting 1 Gbit/s (>700 Mbit/s) connections on my PC, but now it's stuck at 100 Mbit/s.

Fiddling with my Ethernet controller doesn't give me a 1000 Mbit/s full duplex mode, previously set to auto-negotiation.

So where do I go for this? I've already checked https://stackexchange.com/sites for the list, but I don't see something for home users ([Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) is business teams).

Answer (score 7):

The [help page](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) for [Server Fault](https://serverfalt.com) indicates that questions about networking in a home environment should go to [Super User](https://superuser.com):

> Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment.
>
> If your question is about:
>
> managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks
> tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these
> deployment to and management of third-party provided information technology platforms
> and is not about:
>
> consumer workstations or networking (which belong on our sister site, [Super User](https://superuser.com):)

Comment: Yes this answers it. Thanks!